# Switch order of differentiation and boundedness of function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider the function $m_t(\theta)$ on the compact interval $t\in [0,T]$. I have shown that
\begin{align*}
|m_t(\theta+h)-m_t(\theta)-h\dot{m}_t(\theta)|^2\leq C|h|^4,
\end{align*}
where $\theta \in (\alpha, \beta)$ with $|\alpha|+|\beta|<\infty$ and $\dot{m}$ is the derivative of $m$ with respect to $\theta.$

I want to show the same inequality for the process $f_t(\theta)\cdot m_t(\theta)$ now where $f(\cdot)$ is a bounded function that is continuously differentiable, i.e. I want to show that
\begin{align*}
|f_t(\theta+h)m_t(\theta+h)-f_t(\theta)m_t(\theta)-h\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(f_t(\theta)m_t(\theta)  \right)|^2\leq C|h|^4.
\end{align*}

Can I change the order of differentiation and applying the boundedness of $f$ and $\dot{f}$ now? I.e. can I say that
\begin{align*}
h\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(f_t(\theta)m_t(\theta)  \right) \leq C\cdot h \cdot \dot{m}_t(\theta)?
\end{align*}
Because then I could use the inequality I have already proven and conclude.